# Producing two dimensional ggplot2 facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which looks like this. head(dataM):

```
  id    NM ORD     ASPL         D         M        MAR MC      MCS NC NR
1  0   NM2 DEG 2.078990 0.1212121 0.2302028 0.11072818  4 14.28571  7  1
2  0   NM2 RAN 2.020202 0.1323232 0.2198613 0.10883135  6 14.28571  7  1
3  0 RESGR DEG 2.191515 0.1181818 0.5499847 0.25096092  5 20.00000  5  1
4  0 RESGR RAN 2.191515 0.1181818 0.5499847 0.25096092  5 20.00000  5  1
5  0    SF DEG 1.893333 0.1169697 0.1659537 0.08765163  6 14.28571  7  1
6  0    SF RAN 1.903232 0.1169697 0.1768355 0.09291323  6 20.00000  5  1
```

The following code:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

fileName = paste("./4.csv", sep = "") # csv file available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm9hd0t5ak74k89/4.csv?dl=0

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)

dataM = melt(mydata,c("id"))
dataM = cbind(dataM,
            colsplit(dataM$variable,
                     pattern = "_",
                     names = c("NM", "ORD", "CAT")))
dataM$variable <- NULL
dataM <- dcast(dataM, ... ~ CAT, value.var = "value")

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))

dataM$NR <- as.integer(dataM$NR)
dataM$ASPL <- as.numeric(dataM$ASPL)

ggplot(dataM, aes(x=NR ,y= ASPL, group=ORD, color=ORD)) +
  geom_point(size = .7,alpha = .3,position="jitter", aes(shape=ORD)) +  ## increased size
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "loess", size = .5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous("ASPL", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(1, 7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous("NR", expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0, 100)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3, face="bold", size=12)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5, face="bold", size=12)) +
  ggtitle("Title") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")) +
  theme(title = element_text(vjust=2)) +
  facet_grid(NM ~.)
```

Produces the rolling plot:

[image]

Now, I need to facet the visualisation in two dimensions so that rows are similar to the existing plot, but 6 more columns are introduced : namely (besides ASPL which is already here) D, M, MAR, MC, MCS and NC.

How to make this work in my piece of code? Do I need to melt my data once again?

Comment: I guess melting is the easiest way, indeed.

Comment: I had to mess with the data a bit, but It does work! cheers!